# How can I get a "break" after an image

Tags: image, itext

Using iTextSharp (4.1.6) in a Xamarin.Forms app.

I have lines of data with CRLF at the end of each. I put these into paragraphs, which I add to the doc.  At then end of many, I add to the doc one or more images (photos).  Works great.

Now, I'd like to have a page break after the last image, so I get a fresh start.

But iText seems to be flowing the text around the image some, and sometimes I don't get that page break, at last not where I want it.  The next paragraph follows immediately after the image.

I tried adding a small paragraph after the image, but this did not solve.  I did find that adding a SECTION seems to cause a good break, but puts some text in that I don't want or need.

I don't seem to find anything like API documentation for this, I've been just working from examples.

It seems like this would be really easy.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> iText seems to be flowing the text around the image some

Indeed, if you add an image to your document which does not fit on the current page anymore (but there still is some place for text on that page), iText does not immediately start a new page but keeps the image in memory and waits for your next content additions. If you then add text, that text first fills the current page, and only if even text does not fit anymore (or if you add another image), a new page is started and the waiting image is added.

You can switch this off using for your `PdfWriter writer` using

```
writer.StrictImageSequence = true;
```

Comment: Wow... Worked perfectly. Thank you.